# How do I get first day of the year and last day of the year in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to fetch a set of information from my database based on `datetime`.
I am currently using these statements to fetch information:

```
$year_posts = $_GET['year'];
if ($_GET['year'] = date("Y")){
    $state_sql = " AND p.start_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') and p.end_date = NOW()";
}
else{
    $state_sql = " AND p.start_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'$year_posts-01-01') and p.end_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'$year_posts-12-31')";
}
```

If my get variable is = 2015. How do I make it so I fetch all the information from `2015-01-01 00:00:00` to current date?

And same goes for 2014. How can I fetch ALL information from `2014-01-01 00:00:00` to `2014-12-31 23:59:59`?

I've tried looking it up on different threads, but I simply can't figure it out.
Any help?

Comment: If you are looking BETWEEN two dates, the second date is exclusive (i.e. you can use 2015-01-01 00:00:00 and you'll get nothing from 2015).

Comment: @SteveFenton I am looking for between dates :) What do you mean by exclusive?

Comment: What is the date format in your SQL table for `p.start_date` and `p.end_date`?

Comment: note- `mysql` and `sql-server` are not the same.

Comment: So if I were to say `BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-01 00:00:00'` - that would be ALL of 2014 and NONE of 2015.

Comment: Do you mean to be assigning `$_GET['year']` to the value of `date("Y")` or do you want to check if they are the same?

Comment: @aCarella Ongoing events use this query: $state_sql = " AND p.start_date <= NOW() and p.end_date >= NOW()";

Comment: I wish to query for the whole year of 2014 if I get 2014. However, for 2015 I only wish to query the dates from the beginning of 2015 until TODAY

Comment: Your schema is weird. The table normally get only 1 date field (let say `created_date`) then you just code 

WHERE create_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') and  NOW()

And  

WHERE DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'$year_posts-01-01') AND  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'$year_posts-12-31')

Something like you show in the topic.

Comment: @ChainarongTangsurakit Does this work for 2015? Where I only wish to have from the first day of the year until TODAY. and not beyond?

Comment: If you use between `Y-01-01 TO NOW()`. Yes, it would work.

Comment: @GjertGjersund: See my answer. You can manage the dates on PHP end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you trying to figure out.

```
$year_posts = $_GET['year'];
if ($year_posts == date("Y")){
    $state_sql = " AND p.start_date >= '".date('Y')."-01-01 00:00:00' and p.end_date <= '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'";
}
else{
    $state_sql = " AND p.start_date >= '{$year_posts}-01-01 00:00:00' and p.end_date <= '{$year_posts}-12-31 23:59:59'";
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. I've been trying to figure it out for hours! :)

Comment: @GjertGjersund: Great !! No worries that's why we are here to help each other :) It would be great if you accept it as answer and upvote :)

Comment: Yeah, good to have a community like this :) Just took over the job for someone else, so it's slightly different way to program than what I am used to :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the get all records from the beginning to the end of the year, just check the year

```
$state_sql = " AND YEAR(p.start_date) = $year_posts and YEAR(p.end_date) = $year_posts";
```

Comment: This works for 2014, however I'm trying to get for 2015 aswell. From the first day of the year until TODAY :)

Comment: Correction: It works for the whole year of 2014, however, How can I adjust it to work for 2015. From day 1 until TODAY, and none of the dates beyond? :)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fetch ALL information from 2014-01-01 00:00:00 to 2014-12-31
>   23:59:59 ?

With this query:

```
SELECT * FROM something WHERE date BETWEEN [startdate] AND [enddate]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using "LIKE" for that case:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateCol LIKE "2014%"
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(dateCol) LIKE "2014%"
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(dateCol) LIKE "2014-__-__"
```

All of them are working.

**EDIT:** I've seen your comment > from 2014 till today:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(dateCol) > "2014-00-00"
```

Comment: By that comment I ment that it only worked when the URL has 2014 in it. However, when it contains 2015. I wish to have all entries from the first day of 2015 until TODAY, and not the rest beyond today.

Comment: Haha, alright. I missunderstood it. Anyway, the originals are still in it.

Comment: I am not ment to edit anything else than the code I have added. There for using WHERE date is not available.

Comment: Hard to say for me without a view how the table looks like. start_date and end_date are both columns in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming that p.start_date and p.end_date are in timestamp or datetime format.

```
$state_sql = "
  AND DATE_FORMAT(p.start_date) >= '$year_posts-01-01'
  AND DATE_FORMAT(p.end_date) <= '$year_posts-12-31'
";
```

Comment: As he said this columns are from type DateTime you can pick out the date only by using DATE(). No need to format it. Check my edit.

Comment: Never said anything else. I just noticed using the implemented functionality of DateTime would be smarter instead of formatting it or even worse going with Concat and placing everything by your own.